# Sample config.xml for phonegap ios

Tags: ios, cordova

Can any one share me sample config.xml for ios which include the configuration of app icons and splash screensfor all devices?

App got crashed when i include the below code in config.xml

```
<icon src="icon/ios/icon-57.png" /> <icon src="icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" /> <icon src="icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
```

Need help on this

Answer (score 1):

This is the icons section from my config.xml...

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
```

It looks like the first icon tag you have would break it, as there's no attributes.

Comment: Thanks.But it doesn't work.Im using phonegap 2.5.0.Again i got the parser error on config.xml

Comment: Did you remove the incomplete icon tag that you showed in your code?